# How to disable right click of parent swf

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder

How to disable right click of parent .swf from child .swf, 
I have no aceess of parent swf.

Comment: do you mean you want to disable the right click context menu?

Comment: @andygoestohollywood: Yes

Answer (score 1):

you can see all the available options for dealing with the context menu here: [Adobe Help: Context Menu](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/ContextMenu.html).  I dont know that I understand exacely how you have no acess to parent swf from child swf...  that mean parent class from child class?   if you are unsure, `trace(this.parent);` and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

this works fine for me:

```
stage.showDefaultContextMenu=false;
```